# How to include parameters in the path of a list in SAPUI5

Tags: xml, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I'm trying to populate a list in SAPUI5. The path of the items variable should consist of a parameter, which is uncapsulated by apostrophies. When I run the code, the list is empty.

I suspect the issue is due to the apostrophies, but I have already tried to use &apos instead of '. What I'm trying here is hardcoded, as I will fix that once it works.

I'm using SAP Web IDE.

Calling the OData service from a browser, gives me the expected result, of two entries.

The code snippet below shows my current items path:

```
<List id="list" items="{oDataModel>/path1('parameters')/path2}">
```

EDIT:
It seems the problem is that at every call to the OData service, "?$skip=0&top=20" is added at the end. This is not a valid call, when specifying parameters as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right and it is the '. SAPUI5 tries to convert the items property into a JSON object so the extra ' is confusing that.

Try:

```
<List id="list" items="{path : 'oDataModel>/path1(\'parameters\')/path2'}">
```

Or alternatively, if you're just specifying a path, you can use the shorthand:

```
<List id="list" items="{oDataModel>/path1('parameters')/path2}">
```

but that won't allow you to specify additional properties etc.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either:

`items="{path : 'ZSOTS_IM_INV_SRV>/HeaderSet(Iblnr=\'0100000444\',Gjahr=\'2001\')/PositionSet'}"`

The list is still empty. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to realize the binding via your controller.
You have assigned an id to your list, so you can easily retrieve the control in your Controller.

I believe using `\'`can't be interpreted correctly in XML and thus it won't work like this.

You could try the following in your controller:

```
var oList = this.getView().byId("list");

    //necessary to define what kind of control should be rendered per item.
    var template = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                       title: "{WebAddress}"
                   });

oList.bindItems("/HeaderSet(Iblnr='01000004444', Gjahr='2001')/PositionSet", template);
```

Comment: I'm using a CustomListItem, and not a StandardListItem. Thus the property "title", does not seem to be used for the CustomListItem?

Comment: I got closer to the solution by doing the following in my controller (I'm using another OData service, for testing):

   `var oList = oView.byId("list");
   var template = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
    content: oView.byId("customListItem").getContent(),
    title: "{WebAddress}"
   });
   var parameter = "'HT-1000'";
   oList.bindItems("ZMM_BAPI>/ProductListSet(" + parameter + ")", template);`

The list is still not populated, and I suspect it could be due to missing authorities on the back-end system. I'll look into that.

Comment: well, start by just trying the code I've provided, if you see data in your standarlistitems, you know it is something with the solution you've wrote or backend :)

Comment: When using your code with a StanardListItem, or the one above with a CustomListItem, I recieve this error: **"System query options '$orderby,$skip,$top,$skiptoken,$inlinecount' are not allowed in the requested URI"**

Comment: and are you sending any of those query options? because in your initial sample you aren't

Comment: I'm not, this is what my binding looks like: `var oList = this.getView().byId("testList");

   var template = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: "{WebAddress}"
   });

   oList.bindItems("ZMM_BAPI>/ProductListSet('HT-1000')", template);`

Comment: Since you aren't passing any of those parameters I think this is caused by a wrong setting /implementation in backend. Maybe googling will help you further because I have no backend knowledge yet :)